# Run J2ME app on device

Tags: java-me

I have made simple j2me app for gps showing latitude longitude.

CLDC 1.0 MIDP 2.0

I want to run it on HTC widows phone.

Please help me how to do this.

Hope to hear from you soon.

Regrads,

Parmanand Soni

Comment: thank you sir. Please tell me url or server name where i can upload my jar/jad file and also is it necessary to upload both jar and jad file??

Answer (score 0):

Every time i tried copying the jar/jad file to my memory card and then execute it, it never worked.

So I usually upload the jar/jad file somewhere on the web, and then use that url to download the file using the phone where i want the app installed, after the download it usually install the jar/jad file automatically.

I use to that that with feature (low-end) phones, and don't think it would be any different with an HTC.

Answer (score 0):

You need install Java2ME virtual machine on your Windows Mobile device and then run compiled/combined jar file. Refer to documentation of certain JVM.

For example:

- Mysaifu JVM - http://www2s.biglobe.ne.jp/~dat/java.../index_en.html
- CrEme - http://www.nsicom.com/Default.aspx?tabid=138
  .

Comment: I have HTC Touch Diamond (not CDMA), Is it J2ME enabled?? or i need to install CrEme?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have idea. But HTC Diamond is shipped with Microsoft Windows Mobile 6.0, also as I understood HTC usually provide its WM installations with Esmertec JBed J2ME machine. Please check for applications you have installed. If so, it should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

As the previous answers state; in order to be able to run JavaME apps, you need to have a JavaME VM installed on the device.

Windows Mobile phones are usually shipped with Esmertec JBed, as Nokilay Antipov also says. Its icon is a big red "e". If Esmertec JBed is not installed, you can probably find it online. But JBed is not your only option.

My personal favorite JavaME VM is phoneME, downloadable here for many platforms, including Windows Phone 6:
http://davy.preuveneers.be/phoneme/?q=node/10

I found phoneME after lots and lots of searching for a good JavaME VM for Android, and in my opinion it is definitely the best one for Android. I've also tested it on a Windows Mobile 2003 Pocket PC with success.

The only problem with JavaME VM's like these for smartphones, is that most of the time they come with no or else very little JSR support. It says directly on the phoneME page that it does not support additional JSR like bluetooth, so I don't expect it to support GPS either, which you need for your app. I suspect you have to be lucky to find a JavaME VM for Windows Mobile 6 that supports stuff like that. But you can give it a try.

Notice, that with some JavaME VMs, you can't install the MIDlets by clicking the jar in the native filemanager. You have to launch the JavaME VM's filemanager install, and select to install from there. This is the case with phoneME on the platforms I've tried.